# NSFetchRequest two entities and put them in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I am trying to fill a tableview with NSFetchRequest with 2 entities using this code:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *forms;


    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"names"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"forms"];

    self.forms = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    self.forms = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil] mutableCopy];


    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

now I know right now that self.forms is overwritten with the second fetch, but I dont know how to accomplish putting everything in the self.forms array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.forms = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
[self.forms addObjectsFromArray:[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil] mutableCopy]];
```

Comment: AHH yes thats it, I had tried addArrayFromArray but that didnt do it. addObjects did the trick! Thank you. Will accept answer when times up.